# Android Widget Size

Tags: android, android-widget

Can anyone tell me how to make a flexible AppWidgets in Android according to the screen size?
I want to make a full screen widget, but when the screen size changes, I want to make it flexible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to make a full screen widget

You cannot make a full-screen app widget.

You can create an app widget that takes up a certain number of cells, by following [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData), which show you how to provide dimensions in `dip` that equate to a certain number of cells. Exactly how many cells a given home screen application will support is up to the home screen author.

In general, you want your app widget to be as small as possible, not as large as possible. A user may not have room anywhere for a large app widget.